# Cannot authenticate via pkce flutter app with keycloak using openid_client

Tags: flutter, keycloak, openid-connect, pkce

I have the following KeyCloak Client config, to use pkce authentication flow:

```
Realm: REALM

Client ID:              pkce-client
Client Protocol:        openid-connect
Access Type:            public
Standard Flow Enabled:  ON
Valid Redirect URIs:    http://localhost:4200/ 

Advanced Settings:
Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method: S256
```

I try to authenticate in a flutter App with iOS Simulator via openid_client
https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client like this

```
  authenticate() async {

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://$localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM');
    var clientId = 'pkce-client';
    var scopes = List<String>.of(['profile', 'openid']);
    var port = 4200;
    var redirectUri = Uri.parse(http://localhost:4200/);

    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);

    urlLauncher(String url) async {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }

    var authenticator = new Authenticator(
        client,
        scopes: scopes,
        port: port,
        urlLancher: urlLauncher,
        redirectUri: redirectUri,
    );

    var auth = await authenticator.authorize();
    var token= await auth.getTokenResponse();
    return token;
  }
```

But it only gives me this web view:
[image]

The Terminal where KeyCloak is running gives me the following lines:

```
INFO  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpointChecker] (default task-34) PKCE enforced Client without code challenge method.
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-34) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=REALM, clientId=pkce-client, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_request, response_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/, response_mode=query
```

When using Postman it worked and it provided me the Login page:
[image]

But I have additional parameters there, which I do not know where to add them in `Authenticator(..)` when using openid_client, state is automatically added.

```
state: <state>
code_challenge: <code-challenge>
code_challenge_method: S256
```

Do I need to add these code_challenge parameters somewhere in the openid_client method?

Or do I need to change the redirect URL when using an App? I tried with the package_name like proposed here (https://githubmemory.com/repo/appsup-dart/openid_client/issues/32), but it did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the source code](https://github.com/appsup-dart/openid_client/blob/c9ace4306fab39881ad8de99ced37ceb7e2b4f0b/lib/openid_client_io.dart#L21-L23):

```
      : flow = redirectUri == null
            ? Flow.authorizationCodeWithPKCE(client)
            : Flow.authorizationCode(client)
```

You have specified `redirectUri`, so `authorizationCode` flow was used. But you want `authorizationCodeWithPKCE` flow in this case. So just make sure `redirectUri` is null and correct PKCE flow (with correct url parameters, e.g. code_challenge) will be used.

Comment: Is there maybe a possibility to use a custom login and registration page built with flutter and just sending the credentials?

Comment: Do you know how to logout with the openid_client?

Comment: I still have that error with invalid_scopes even after all those changes. My redirectUri is null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the `redirectUri:null` and set the port to 3000 ( you can use your port ).

after that you need to add the redirect uri in keycloak like this `http://localhost:3000/` .it will do the trick

(what happening is when you send the redirect uri as null value, open_id client use the pkce flow and use the default url)